# How to Pass data from table data to pop-up modal (Using Yii Framework)

Tags: php, yii

How can i pass data from my table to a pop-up.
This is how i did it in my table:
I populate the table from my database using controllers and models

```
    <table class="table table-striped table-checkable" id="demo-dtable-02" aria-describedby="DataTables_Table_0_info">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Subject: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 220px;">??</th><th class="sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Date: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 79px;">??</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">

            <?php
                    foreach ($my_page_data['text_list']as $text_list_key => $text_list_data){
            ?>

            <tr class="odd">
                <td class=" "><a href="#" onclick="viewText(<?php echo $text_list_data['id'] ?>)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-text" ><?php $msg = $text_list_data['msg']; ?></a></td>
            <div id="<?php echo $inbox_list_data['id'] ?>" data-content="<?php $msg = $inbox_list_data['message']?>"></div> <!-- i used this as a hidden div for the data to be passed because i dont know other ways -->                                                                          
                <td class=" "><?php $date =  $text_list_data['date_updated'];?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Then i used a script to pass the data...

```
    <script>
        function viewInbox(id){
            $('#inbox-message-body').text($('#'+id).attr('data-content'));
        }
    </script>
```

And then the the clicked data will be displayed here:

```
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class=" . . .">
            <div class="..">
                <span class="view-label">From:</span> MY OTHER DATA <!--TODO: -->
                <br>
                <span class="view-label">To:</span> MY DATA<!--TODO: -->
                <br>
            </div>

        </div>
            <!--TODO: Message body-->  I
       <span id="message-body" class="span8"></span> 

    </div>
```

This code are just in one file.
The page im creating is like. I have a table of messages. Then to view message is to click it and a pop-up will appear.

Any insights?

Your help is greatly appreaciated.

Answer (score 0):

The way i do it is i assign modal template to a different controller, and then call it via ajax request like this.

```
$(".modalCaller").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: POST,
        url: "/insert/modal/controller/here",
        data: {id: $(this).data("id")},
        success: function(data){
           data.appendTo("body").modal("show");
        }
    })
});
```

And just drop your modal into another view.

Comment: No, `body` is just html body tag - you're appending your modal to the end of the document. And `.modal("show")` is from twitter-bootstrap, i saw that modal-body class and thought you use it for modal. Just use `.show()` or similar code.